# Issue with a Python continue statement in a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm learning how to use a continue statement in a while loop and wrote this code as a practice example. I'm hoping to get a few responses of 'undergrad', 'grad' and 'phd' before printing the final message. Can I accomplish this with continue?

```
print("Welcome to Higher Education U. Please partake in the following roll call.")
name = input("What is your name? ")
level = input("Which program are you in: undergrad, grad, phd or other? ")

while True:
    if level == 'undergrad':
        print(f"Hi {name}, you are one of the first undergrads.")
        continue
    elif level == 'grad':
        print(f"Hi {name}, you are one of the first grad students.")
        continue
    elif level == 'phd':
        print(f"Hi {name}, you are one of the first phd students.")
        continue
    else:
        print(f"Hi {name}, please consider applying to HEU!")
        break
```

Comment: Please include a description of what went wrong.

Comment: What is the point of continue here? Is this just example code or are you actually trying to use this? Also you need to put the name/level input inside of the loop or you will only ever use the original inputs.

Comment: Consdier stepping through the code manually. Pencil and paper type of thing. If you get an undergrad and contine, you are back to the top of the while... but you haven't changed any data so the undergrad section will keep running and running.

Comment: May be want is to read and display messages continuously. If that is what you want `remove all continue` place `name = input("What is your name? ")`  and 
`level = input("Which program are you in: undergrad, grad, phd or other? ")` inside `while` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while` loops automatically continue when you reach the end of the indented code suite, so there is no need for your `if` suites to do it manually. But you need to put the prompts in the `while` so it keeps prompting for more data as you go.

Your code could be

```
print("Welcome to Higher Education U. Please partake in the following roll call.")

while True:
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    level = input("Which program are you in: undergrad, grad, phd or other? ")
    if level == 'undergrad':
        print(f"Hi {name}, you are one of the first undergrads.")
    elif level == 'grad':
        print(f"Hi {name}, you are one of the first grad students.")
    elif level == 'phd':
        print(f"Hi {name}, you are one of the first phd students.")
    else:
        print(f"Hi {name}, please consider applying to HEU!")
        break
```

You've got the same algorithm for multiple values and you could put them into a container and only implement the algorithm once. You want to track number of applicants, so a dict recording the names makes sense.

```
print("Welcome to Higher Education U. Please partake in the following roll call.")

types = {"undergrad":[], "grad":[], "phd":[]}

while True:
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    level = input("Which program are you in: undergrad, grad, phd or other? ")
    try:
        normalized = level.casefold()
        types[normalized].append(name)
        if len(types[normalized]) < 3:
            print(f"Hi {name}, you are one of the first {level}s.")
        if min(len(names) for names in types.values()) > 3:
            print("Classes full")
            break
    except KeyError:
        print(f"Hi {name}, please consider applying to HEU!")
        break
```

Comment: Placing the input statements within the `while` loop solved the problem I was trying to tackle.